# Renaming the "gersgorin-sets" tag

Tags: support, tag-management

I think this tag should be renamed "gershgorin-sets".

According to Wikipedia, the correct spelling can be Geršgorin, Gerschgorin, Gerszgorin, Gershgorin, הירשהאָרן, Hirshhorn or Hirschhorn (Гершгорин, not listed, should also be considered). That does not include Gersgorin, without [haček](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Caron). The most common spelling in english (and the one used on Wikipedia) seems to me to be Gershgorin.

According to [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/87437/how-to-rename-a-tag), only moderators can do that, and it should be discussed on Meta, hence my question here.

See

- https://math.stackexchange.com/tags/gersgorin-sets/info
- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semyon_Aranovich_Gershgorin

Comment: That's the spelling (Gershgorin) I'm familiar with.

Comment: I think Geršgorin is a russian, how come "Гершгорин" is not on the list???

Comment: @achillehui Perfectly right!

Comment: I agree. If noone objects I'll implement it soon. Ping me if I forget.

Answer (score 4):

It is done. I even resisted the temptation to translate the name and call it [hartshorne-sets](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/hartshorne-sets).

Comment: Thank you!.....

Comment: I will just add the new name in a "clickable" form: ([tag:gershgorin-sets]). The old form [is now a synonym](https://math.stackexchange.com/tags/gershgorin-sets/synonyms). The [tag-excerpt](https://math.stackexchange.com/posts/653836/revisions) and [tag-wiki](https://math.stackexchange.com/posts/653835/revisions) were taken from the old version - maybe somebody with good knowledge of this area might have some possible improvements for [the tag-info](https://math.stackexchange.com/tags/gershgorin-sets/info).